# created_at column is taking junk date in magento when editing the customer

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I’m using Magento 1.6.1CE.
I have set the default time zone to Australia/Perth. my server also running in the same time Zone.

when creating the customer there is no issue with created_at column in DB and Customer Since column in admin html.

But when edit the details and Update no problem in saving but Customer Since column is taking some junk date like 30/11/00-1 1:30:00 AM or 01/01/1970 9:30:00 AM. so I’m unable to edit it next time(showing Exception handling is disabled)
when I see in the DB created_at it is showing 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Please let me know how can I solve this problem. I’m new to Magento Coding.

Thanks in Advance…

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue once. It's because Magento assumes a specific date format, which depends on your locale.

By default Magento uses format Month/Day/Year. In your case it seems like Magento acutally shifts Day and Month. So, make sure that "Locale" and "Timezone" in `System > Configuration > General > Locale Options` match.

If they match and you still get this issue, then you will can try to rewrite customer edit block or a controller action.